# Put a text from a JSON file on HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, video

i hope that someone can help me.

I have this JSON file that i can't eddit (comes from external source).

```
{
  "assetsLocation": "http://example.com/assets",
  "objects": [
{
  "name":"myVideo",
  "bg": "myVideo.mp4",
  "im": "myVideo.jpg",
  "sg": "myAudio.mp3",
  "txts": [
    {
      "txt": "Nice!!!",
      "time": 2.1
    },
    {
      "txt": "Go ahead!!",
      "time": 10.3
    }
  ]
},
....
}
```

So i need to create an HTML5 video that loops until the audio is ended(works), and to put the "txt" content over the video when video is on time equals "time".

I tried a lot of things and i'm stuck for days on this task.

The actual ugly code is :

```
<div id="video-container" class="flex">
    <video id="v" loop muted></video>
    <button id="play">Play/Pause</button>
    <audio id="a"></audio>
</div>
```

This achive the play until audio stops:

```
    var vid = document.getElementById("v");
    var aud = document.getElementById("a");


    var isPlaying = false;

    function playPause(a) {
      if (a != undefined && isPlaying ) {
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log(a.txt); //this does not work
        },a.time * 1000);
      } else if (isPlaying) {
       vid.pause();
       aud.pause();

      } else {
        vid.play();
        aud.play();
      }
    };

    vid.onplaying = function() {
        isPlaying = true;

        setInterval(function(){ // Stop video when audio ends;
            vid.load();
            aud.load();
        },aud.duration * 1000);

    };
    vid.onpause = function() {
        isPlaying = false;
    };
```

And inside the $_ajax request i have this function :

```
function loadJsonFile(data) {


var url = data.assetsLocation + "/";

$(data['objects']).each(function(a){


    var img ="<img id='card-img' src='" + url + this.im + "' alt='"+     this.name +"'>";
    var listItem = "<li class='card'>"+img+"<span class='card-name'>"+this.name+"</span></li>";

    var thisVideo = this.bg;
    var thisAudio = this.sg;
    var thisTexts = this.txts;


    $('#cards').append(listItem);

    $('.card:last').on('click',function(){
        controles("liga-modal");            
        vid.src = url + thisVideo;
        aud.src = url + thisAudio;
    });
    $('#play').on('click',function(){
        playPause(thisTexts);
    })

});
```

Well, i know that is a lot of wrong stuff going on and i'm studing a lot to a better understanding of Javascript and programming. I hope you could give me some advices about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you post what you have tried? [How to ask good questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I eddited the post, it's my first time here, thx for the advice!

Comment: I guess `a.time` is not defined when you call `playPause(thisTexts);`

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the time you set for your interval. Here is your function `playPause`

```
function playPause(a) {
      if (a != undefined && isPlaying ) {
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log(a.txt); //this does not work
        },a.time * 1000);
      } else if (isPlaying) {
       vid.pause();
       aud.pause();

      } else {
        vid.play();
        aud.play();
      }
    };
```

Now you call this function with `playPause(thisTexts);`. `thisTexts` seems to be a string, so `a.time` is not defined. So you won't get the result of the operation `a.time * 1000` that you need for the timer.

Comment: `this.txts` is refering to an array of objects, and when i call it from console i get the result of txts propertys of all objects including the ones that not have this property, and getting undefined.

Comment: Could you post here the `console.log(thisTexts)`? If `this.txts` is an array, it means that it does not have a property `time`meaning that we cannot access `this.txts.time`. And if we can't access `this.txts.time`, we don't have `a.time` either.